# Issues with the script on ajax request

Tags: php, yii

I am facing a problem on adding a record on ajax which renders partial with other two ajaxified links for edit and delete. But i get the error that the jquery is not a function.

By searching the web for solutions i got the following.
Make the fourth parameter to true and register the script.

```
$this->renderPartial("_part", array('parms' => $model), false, true);
```

And to register a script i added the following line in the main view file.

```
 <?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript("jquery"); ?>
```

And in the library it says.

```
public CClientScript registerScript(string $id, string $script, integer $position=NULL)
```

From the above line I get that the id must be the id of the script tag. like; 
`<script id="someid"></script>`. But i couldn't get the second part as I want to register the js which are in the script tags in the main page.

How do i do this?

Comment: In order to register jQuery you have to use: `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript("jquery");`

Comment: @Ezze still the same error. Is the string "jquery" the id of the script tag?

Comment: The second parameter of `registerScript()` function is a JavaScript code to be included in `script` tag. If you want to register some JS code from existing file you have to use [registerScriptFile()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerScriptFile-detail) method of `CClientScript`.

Comment: [registerCoreScript()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#registerCoreScript-detail) method has only one argument - a name of core script. It could be `jquery` or `jquery.ui` which are already included in Yii.

Comment: hmm i got it thanks. But still i get the error jquery.blockUI is not a function. :(

Comment: Probably, jQuery [blockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#download) plugin is missed. You have to download plugin's JavaScript file and register it using `registerScriptFile()` method. I'm not sure but maybe `jquery.ui` core script is to be registered too.

Comment: @Ezze I registered all of the three scripts at the end of other script tags. But it did not reflect any change.

Answer (score 0):

After you do `renderPartial` and load your content with ajax you load your scripts once more.

For example you got some jQueryUI datepicker, it wont work inside of rendered part. Even if you'll register script right and so on you'll need to reinit object to make your widget work.

Load your scripts in rendered part is very bad idea cause you'll have double loads. Then you'll need to delete scripts from script map and load on your pages them with your hands.
So load all scripts on your page. Add this:

`if (Yii::app()->request->getIsAjaxRequest()) {

Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['*.js'] = false;

Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['*.css'] = false;

$this->renderpartial('someview',array())
}
`

Actually this works but its efficient and bad.

I had similar problem. My solution is simple. Leave in rendered part only content. What i mean:

1st case. You need some confirmation page with additional details for example. So after user clicking somwhere you show him this 1 without previous. In this cases you can use `render()`. It wont cause page reload and you'll not have problems with widgets. On page load you can show something sweet like wheel or smthing.

2nd case. You need to show additional fields or something on forms , etc. In this case javascript is your friend. Ajax not needed here.

3rd case. Load some additional content with saving previous and widgets inside. In this case you probably will have structure like

```
_______________
| Page        |
|             |
|Add content  |
|_____________|
```

You need to init all your scripts and objects in your page. Load only content with `renderpartial`. Thats what it designed for. For example write structure of content, make it hidden, on succes populate it with content and show to user.

Its really frustrating problem in yii. But in 90% of cases you can avoid it with small changes. 
Here is thread about this problem. http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/10427-ajax-clientscript